# Unable to deselect option with Chosen and Knockout Binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, jquery-chosen

When trying to deselect the currently selected item in chosen through a knockout binding it seems to get reset back to what it was before the reset:

Here's the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/WPpH2/7

Select jQuery from the drop down and click "clear" to see this behavior.

Here's how the data bind is being done:

```
data-bind="value: selected, chosen: {}">
```

Any thoughts on how I can make this actually reset?

Comment: I was playing around this this a little bit and found that destroying and reinitializing chosen reset the selected item. This seems less than ideal: http://jsfiddle.net/WPpH2/8/

Comment: Here's another example with a set button. http://jsfiddle.net/WPpH2/9/

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're seeing this is because of how the control works. When you click clear, you set the observable to null. The plugin then tries to find an option that has the value null. Because it doesn't find it, it resets your selection to what was last selected.

In your jsfiddle, if you change this line:

```
myViewModel.selected(null);
```

to this line:

```
myViewModel.selected("");
```

then your example will work. The reason is that you have an option where the value is an empty string.

Also, if you want your plugin to update on the UI, you will need to use this as well:

```
$(".chosen").trigger("chosen:updated");
```